# How to let the html parser know that '&para' is not the HTML-safe sequences?

Tags: python, html

I want to get the href of the `<a>` tag using the code below.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class Y_HTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def gethref(self, html):
        self.feed(html)
        return self.href

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            d = {}
            for attr in attrs:
                d[attr[0]] = attr[1]
            if d.get('seed') == 'need_phonelogin-login':
                self.href = d.get('href')

htmlstring = '''
    <h5 class="am-ft-gray am-ft-mb-20">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/sub?awid=123&params=456" seed="need_phonelogin-login">链接</a>
</h5>'''

parser = Y_HTMLParser()
href = parser.gethref(htmlstring)
```

However, 'para' is the HTML-safe sequences reference to character '¶'. So the href will become 'http://www.example.com/sub?awid=123¶ms=456'

How do I solve this?

Comment: `&para` is not `¶`, `&para;` is. `&params` should not turn into `¶ms`. The parser is incorrect if it's really doing that.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is invalid HTML, `&` should be encoded as `&amp;`. But HTML's often are invalid and parsers have to deal with it. What you coud do is detect that the code following `&` is wrong (i.e. not followed by a recognizable name and `;`) and then assume that this is just a stray `&`.

Comment: Ah, this is the builtin parser in Python. You might want to use BeautifulSoup with `lxml` if you can't fix the HTML as @zvone pointed out: `BeautifulSoup(htmlstring, "lxml").find("a")["href"] #=> 'http://www.example.com/sub?awid=123&params=456'`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks for your advise. the issue was fixed.